# Jquery UI droppable not working with html 5 draggable

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui

I have a div with HTML draggable applied on it, and a container with jquery UI droppable applied on it.
**Problem is when I drag my HTML div, and come over droppable container, container's droppable not working.**
I cannot use HTML droppable events because I need to fire over,out,enter events exactly when draggable comes over,out and enter, which In case of HTML droppable, not working. (it consider's mouse pointer, not dragged element).

### HTML

---

HTML draggable :

```
<div draggable="true" (dragstart)="handleDragStart($event)" (dragend)="handleDragEnd($event)"></div>
```

---

Jquery droppable's HTML :

```
<div class="large-container">
<div class="column-cell dynamically-created-div"></div>
<div class="column-cell dynamically-created-div"></div>
<div class="column-cell dynamically-created-div"></div>
...n number of droppable cells

</div>
```

### JS

```
$('.column-cell').droppable(
  {
    tolerance: 'touch',
    out: function (event: any, ui: any) {
      let columnId = $(event.target).data('columnid');
      console.log('out from ', columnId);
    },
    over: function (event: any, ui: any) {
      let columnId = $(event.target).data('columnid');
      console.log('Over on ', columnId);
    },
    drop: (event: any, ui: any) => {
      let columnId = $(event.target).data('columnid');
      console.log('dropped to  ', columnId);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Would suggest adding the `accept` option.

Comment: Also a lot of this does not appear to be JavaScript. The argument syntax does not look right and `=>` is not part of the syntax. `let` is older as well.

Comment: Did you read through this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqueryui-draggable-with-html5-drag-and-drop

Comment: So far, I can see that the draggable element is not a jQuery Object and I think droppable is not willing to accept it for this reason. Trying to see if the two can co-mingle. Is there a reason you are not using draggable and droppable?

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of research. This should pass Native HTML5 to jQuery UI Droppable for each of the events.

Test Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ujqmxqjv/17/

**HTML**

```
<div draggable="true"></div>

<div class="large-container">
  <div class="column-cell dynamically-created-div"></div>
  <div class="column-cell dynamically-created-div"></div>
  <div class="column-cell dynamically-created-div"></div>
  ...n number of droppable cells
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Tell jQuery to include this property
$.event.addProp("dataTransfer");

$(function() {
  function pass2Drop(event, eventType) {
    var f = $(event.target).droppable("option", eventType);
    var el = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    var ui = {
      draggable: $(el),
      helper: $(el),
      position: {
        top: event.pageY,
        left: event.pageX
      },
      offset: {
        top: event.offsetY,
        left: event.offsetX
      }
    }
    f.call(event.target, event, ui);
  }

  $("div[draggable='true']").on("dragstart", function(ev) {
    var dt = ev.dataTransfer;
    dt.setData("text/html", ev.target.outerHTML);
  });

  $('.column-cell').droppable({
    tolerance: 'touch',
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    out: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("jQuery UI Out on " + $(e.target).index(), ui);
    },
    over: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("jQuery UI Over on " + $(e.target).index(), ui);
    },
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("jQuery UI Drop on " + $(e.target).index(), ui);
      console.log("Dropped: ", ui.draggable);
    }
  });

  $(".column-cell").on("dragover", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Native Drag Over on " + $(ev.target).index());
    pass2Drop(ev, "over");
  }).on("dragleave", function(ev) {
    console.log("Native Drag Leave on " + $(ev.target).index());
    pass2Drop(ev, "out");
  }).on("drop", function(ev) {
    if (ev.stopPropagation) {
      ev.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
    }
    console.log("Native Drop on " + $(ev.target).index());
    pass2Drop(ev, "drop");
  });
});
```

I tried to `.trigger()` events, but this worked out better. We harvest the event callback from the Droppable, create the `ui` and pass the `event` and `ui` to the function. This has the effect of triggering it from native events and passing in the expected elements so that our jQuery UI callbacks operate properly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but it seems like the fiddle you shared does not exist any more (404), can you share it again, or link to JSBIN?

Comment: Ok, pass2Drop works! Thanks for the solution, but there is 1 major problem, event "dragover" is triggered ONLY when mouse pointer is touching target droppable, unlike jquery droppable (which invokes quickly because of the tolerance = 'touch' property)

Comment: @Awadhoot this is because the dragged item not a jQuery Object. If you want to make use of that feature, then use `.draggable()` and do not use Native HTML5 DnD. Otherwise this works on the mouse. You can add spacing for the dragged item if you want.